# union not happening with Spark transform

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a Spark stream in which records are flowing in. And the interval size is 1 second. 
I want to union all the data in the stream. So i have created an empty RDD , and then using transform method, doing union of RDD (in the stream) with this empty RDD.
I am expecting this empty RDD to have all the data at the end.
But this RDD always remains empty.

Also, can somebody tell me if my logic is correct.

```
JavaRDD<Row> records = ss.emptyDataFrame().toJavaRDD();
JavaDStream<Row> transformedMessages = messages.flatMap(record -> processData(record))
                    .transform(rdd -> rdd.union(records));

transformedMessages.foreachRDD(record -> {
System.out.println("Aman" +record.count());
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

Dataset ds = ss.createDataFrame(records, schema);
ds.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable");
ds.show();

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, `records` is empty.

Then we have `transformedMessages = messages + records`, but `records` is empty, so we have: `transformedMessages = messages` (obviating the `flatmap` function which is not relevant for the discussion)

Later on, when we do `Dataset ds = ss.createDataFrame(records, schema);` `records` 
 is still empty. That does not change in the flow of the program, so it will remain empty as an invariant over time.

I think what we want to do is, instead of

```
.transform(rdd -> rdd.union(records));
```

we should do:

```
.foreachRDD{rdd => records = rdd.union(records)} //Scala: translate to Java syntax
```

---

That said, please note that as this process iteratively adds to the lineage of the 'records' RDD and also will accumulate all data over time. This is not a job that can run stable for a long period of time as, eventually, given enough data, it will grow beyond the limits of the system.

There's no information about the usecase behind this question, but the current approach does not seem to be scalable nor sustainable.

Comment: Thankyou, i understand your point. 
But then what is the use of transform method? I have read various documents where its said to use Transform method to union the RDD data

Comment: Also, my intention is to create DataSet out of the "records" RDD at some poiint of time. I was thinking of using "forEach" place this code (to create DataSet) , but now that i am unioning the RDDs here, where should i place my code to create the DataSet

Comment: @AmanpreetKhurana could you add some background to the question? What problem are you trying to solve? In my opinion, the current approach will not work over time.